# runtime error '1004' method ' opentext ' of object 'workbooks' failed

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I am trying to open a text file through the following code. I was using this code for quite some time in my PC and it was working. I upgraded my system to Excel 2013 and its not working.

```
fileToOpen = Application _
    .GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    fileToOpen _
    , Origin:=1251, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Even the macro recorded for the same is not working in my upgraded system. Please help. The error appears at `Workbooks.OpenText` line.
The error is

> runtime error '1004' method ' opentext ' of object 'workbooks' failed

Comment: Please provide a sample of your txt file and a [mcve].

Comment: Did you try the Open-method instead of OpenText? `Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileToOpen, Format:=6, Origin:=1251, Delimiter:=Chr(9)`

Comment: @EarlyBird2 it also didn't work

Comment: OK, sorry it didn't help.